# Configuring the ATEC608A with the cryptoauthlib

Tags: c, microcontroller, microchip

I try to configure the ATEC608A with the cryptoauthlib by calling `atcab_write_config_zone()` and passing 128 bytes, which is the size of a configuration. I found an example online, but I can't figure out, nor find a documentation online which bytes I have to configure in which scenario.

Does anyone know how the cryptochip is configured and what exactly I have to set when callig `atcab_priv_write()` for example?

I am able to use certain functionality without configuration:
AES works,
generating keys works,
getting a random number works,
getting version and serial works

I used the following example, but have no idea which bytes influence which functionality:

```
uint8_t g_dev_config[ATCA_CONFIG_SIZE] = {
    0x01,0x23,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x60,0x00,
    0x04,0x05,0x06,0x07,
    0xEE,0x01,0x01,0x00, //15
    0xC0,0x00,0xA1,0x00,
    0xAF,0x2F,0xC4,0x44,
    0x87,0x20,0xC4,0xF4,
    0x8F,0x0F,0x0F,0x0F, //31
    0x9F,0x8F,0x83,0x64,
    0xC4,0x44,0xC4,0x64,
    0x0F,0x0F,0x0F,0x0F,
    0x0F,0x0F,0x0F,0x0F, //47
    0x0F,0x0F,0x0F,0x0F,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF, //63
    0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0x84,0x03,0xBC,
    0x09,0x69,0x76,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, //79
    0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
    0xFF,0xFF,0x0E,0x40,
    0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00, //95
    0x33,0x00,0x1C,0x00,
    0x13,0x00,0x1C,0x00,
    0x3C,0x00,0x3E,0x00,
    0x1C,0x00,0x33,0x00, //111
    0x1C,0x00,0x1C,0x00,
    0x38,0x10,0x30,0x00,
    0x3C,0x00,0x3C,0x00,
    0x32,0x00,0x30,0x00 //127
};
```

I opened an issue on github: [issue](https://github.com/MicrochipTech/cryptoauthlib/issues/44)

Comment: You configure the chip with `atcab_init()`.

Comment: Yes I know, I've done that and as I wrote in the question, I can do certain things, but apparently not everything.

Comment: There is [sha204_defauilt_config](https://github.com/MicrochipTech/cryptoauthlib/blob/master/test/atca_test.c#L75) and test_ecc* configs, but I fail to find a documentation explaining the bytes inside the configuration.

Comment: Yes exactly! I also use the tests to learn, but as you said, there is no documentation on the exact meaning of each byte. I opened an issue on github if you would like to follow that: https://github.com/MicrochipTech/cryptoauthlib/issues/44

Comment: Sounds to me like a locking problem. You cannot use the encryption unless you have locked the area as it will just use the deault keys unless you lock it, but once you have locked it you can not re-configure the device - locking is permanent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [ATECC608A microchip site](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATECC608A) there is [docs AN_8845 - ATSHA204A and ATECC508A Personalization Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/Atmel-8845-CryptoAuth-ATSHA204A-ATECC508A-Personalization-Guide-ApplicationNote.pdf) from which one can read in section `1 Personalize Configuration Zone`:

> The details of these bytes are described below. For more information, please refer to latest ATSHA204A or
>   ATECC508A datasheet.

Well, from [ATSHA204A microchip site](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATSHA204A) from [Complete Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATSHA204A-Data-Sheet-40002025A.pdf) the whole configuration zone is described in `2.1.2 Configuration Zone`:

[image]

Following with description of each field inside the configuration zone. The single slots configuration is in the ATECC608A documentation while the overall confgiuration zone structure is in the ATSHA204A documentation.

Microchip is sometimes known of it's good and extensive documentation. There are numerous doxygens and source codes and examples and more available online on all CryptoAuthLib supported devices.

Comment: Ok I only looked on the ATECC608A site, which only has the summary and some examples, but not the full documentation! Thanks